# Check in a Twig template if the current route belongs from a specific Symfony2 bundle

Tags: symfony, routes, bundle, twig

A Symfony2 app is usually organized around bundles. Each bundle contains (many) controllers. Each controller should be mapped with a route.

Practically speaking, routes are usually stored in a specific file under the `config` folder of the bundle or, eventually, annotated inside each controller.

What I'm looking for is *a way in Twig to identify if the current route belongs from a specific Symfony bundle*. Is it possible?

Please, as a final remark, consider that the route name should follows the namespace of the controller, in my opinion, but it could also be a random but unique name, e.g. `qwer_XX` instead of `ACME_HomeBundle_home`. Hence, we cannot resort to a *namespace-to-route-name* association to do what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html) object, I found a possible solution.

The controller is attached to the `Request` object, hence one can extract it in Twig from the string:

```
app.request.attributes.get('_controller')
```

and so retrieve the bundle name. For instance one can define through a [TwigExtension](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) such a filter function, e.g.

```
public function getFilters() {
    return array(
        ...//other filters
        'bundleName'=>new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'bundleNameFilter'),
    );
}

public static function bundleNameFilter($string){
  return strstr(substr(strstr($string, '\\'), 1), '\\', true);
}
```

Then, in twig use it as follows:

```
{{  app.request.attributes.get('_controller') | bundleName }}
```

Hope it helps.